# Add a counter to track NFTs minted

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang, anchor-test

I am trying to create a counter and increment it on every mint. On adding the counter code after deploying when I test it gives me an error on `anchor run test`:

[image: Error Image on anchor run test]

lib.rs snippets:

```
#[account]
pub struct MintingAccount {
    pub total_mint_count: i64,
}
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintNft<'info> {
    
    #[account(init, payer=mint_authority, space=264)]
    pub minting_account: Account<'info, MintingAccount>,
}
```

```
 pub fn mint(
        ctx: Context<MintNft>,
        metadata_title: String,
        metadata_symbol: String,
        metadata_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        
        system_program::create_account(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::CreateAccount {
                    from: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            //price of nft
            1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 4,
            //space
            82,
            //owner
            &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),
        )?;

        let mut _count = ctx.accounts.minting_account.total_mint_count.clone();

        msg!("total mint count {}: ", _count);

Ok();
}
```

Test case snippet:

```
it("Mint!", async () => {
 const mintKeypair: anchor.web3.Keypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    await program.methods.mint(
      testNftTitle, testNftSymbol, testNftUri
    )
    .accounts({ 

      //some other accounts
      // .....
      // .....

      mintingAccount: mintKeypair.publicKey
    })
    .signers([mintKeypair])
    .rpc();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to initialize MintingAccount every time the mint function is called, this might be a cause for the error.

Comment: Also please add mint-authority to the MintNft struct if you haven't and that should be your signer